# How to read an Apple Crash report (Python + OpenCV)

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, opencv, osx-mavericks

I've been compiling OpenCV 3 from source; works fine on Ubuntu but not on Mavericks. Running `import cv2` causes `Segmentation fault: 11`.

Though I don't expect anyone to know the answer, I'm hoping someone can perhaps help me understand the crash report a bit better, in case it gives any clues as to what's gone wrong:

Full report here: http://pastebin.com/FWK5ETXQ (Stackoverflow concatenated my post!)

```
    Process:         Python [8827]
Path:            /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      Python
Version:         2.7.6 (2.7.6)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [8652]
Responsible:     iTerm [5464]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-04-28 16:46:00.314 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  67697576-7F1E-20B2-A50C-1A53F7573FBC

Sleep/Wake UUID: E85A719E-FE2A-4DE6-AB0E-84D0E97A454C

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100b0e000-0000000100b10000 [    8K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                             000000000000000000 0 + 0
1   org.python.python               0x000000010105a37d PyEval_GetGlobals + 23
2   org.python.python               0x0000000101068ea5 PyImport_Import + 131
3   org.python.python               0x0000000101067687 PyImport_ImportModule + 31
4   cv2.so                          0x0000000100e6e84a initcv2 + 26
5   org.python.python               0x0000000100bb2d7e _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule + 140
6   org.python.python               0x0000000100bb2a8b import_submodule + 274
7   org.python.python               0x0000000100bb2655 load_next + 280
8   org.python.python               0x0000000100bb060c PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 589
9   org.python.python               0x0000000100b96054 builtin___import__ + 135
10  org.python.python               0x0000000100b21967 PyObject_Call + 99
11  org.python.python               0x0000000100ba0867 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 93
12  org.python.python               0x0000000100b9d084 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9321
13  org.python.python               0x0000000100b9aa8a PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1612
14  org.python.python               0x0000000100b9a438 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
15  org.python.python               0x0000000100bba268 run_mod + 53
16  org.python.python               0x0000000100bba084 PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags + 353
17  org.python.python               0x0000000100bb9b93 PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags + 192
18  org.python.python               0x0000000100bb9a3f PyRun_AnyFileExFlags + 60
19  org.python.python               0x0000000100bcb502 Py_Main + 2970
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8fadc5fd start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00000001011052a8  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0xdb0092e49b734ef1  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000101099cb2  rbp: 0x00007fff5f0f0f90  rsp: 0x00007fff5f0f0f88
   r8: 0x0000000004000001   r9: 0x00007fece8c00000  r10: 0x2000000000000200  r11: 0x00000001033170b4
  r12: 0x00007fece9045400  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000100c41e68
  rip: 0x0000000000000000  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000014
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x100b0e000 -        0x100b0ffff +org.python.python (2.7.6 - 2.7.6) <E836C178-A460-3ECB-A191-70E06D9E132B> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x100b17000 -        0x100c07ff7 +org.python.python (2.7.6, [c] 2004-2013 Python Software Foundation. - 2.7.6) <5B675F3C-EBEE-38B8-A3C5-7F242B520409> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
       0x100e24000 -        0x100e26ff7 +readline.so (0) <F821C7FB-8A8B-3181-950D-17DD995191A1> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
       0x100e2c000 -        0x100e4cff7 +libreadline.6.2.dylib (0) <11A375C9-F0E3-3B78-B79E-5C41A1BE06A6> /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.2.dylib
       0x100e63000 -        0x100f89ff7 +cv2.so (0) <A6BC52BD-F4DF-3F51-AD42-FD528F2F71E6> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
       0x100fd4000 -        0x1010befff  org.python.python (2.7.5 - 2.7.5) <0202C38E-0354-34FA-9996-8D2ADCE353D8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
       0x101124000 -        0x101342ff7 +libopencv_core.3.0.dylib (0) <106572BE-11A7-3773-A084-643ED3164058> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.3.0.dylib
       0x1013a0000 -        0x1013e9ff7 +libopencv_flann.3.0.dylib (0) <56183EEC-919C-3EB0-92DA-
```

Comment: You should probably [report the bug](http://code.opencv.org/projects/OpenCV/wiki/WikiStart#Creating-new-tickets) to the OpenCV developers.

Comment: Yeah I did. They told me to fix it and report back when I've figured out what was wrong ;-)

Comment: See if this answer solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24269779/814145