# Segmentation fault and crashing when trying to import opencv

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I have mac os x 10.9. I downloaded opencv-python using homebrew and I have both the python 2.7 and python 3.4 versions off of the main python site, downloaded the usual way with macs. I need to use opencv, but they do not have a download package for macs so I used homebrew:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv
```

When I type python into the terminal, and then type import cv, I get a segmentation error and python quits unexpectedly. The same thing happens in IDLE. For python 3.4, I get a no module error. Here it is:

```
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/aurora_alvarez-buylla/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'

Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
Segmentation fault: 11
```

and then it quits unexpectedly. Does anyone know what is going on? Frankly I have spent way too much time on this opencv issue and am finding it very frustrating. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Chris Muktar pointed in [this thread](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3632) that the problem is caused by the conflict between the system Python and brewed Python. Following that idea, I resolved this issue by removing the system python and re-installing opencv:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ sudo mv python python.bak
$ brew uninstall opencv
$ brew install opencv
```

Comment: Chris here as charged ;) I was compiling OpenCV3 from source, the trick is to make sure that cmake points to the right Python libraries. If you run ccmake .. and switch to advanced mode (press t), find the links to the Python libraries. Cmake gets confused and links some Apple distributed Pythons & some brewed pythons, causing a mess. You want to change all Apple distributed pythons to the brewed ones and everything will be fine.